# The meaning of "feel my conversation in quotation marks"?

Tags: verbs

What does the last part of the below sentence mean? It looks to me grammartically incorrect.

Does it mean "The most familiar things (X,Y,Z) makes me feel at a remove, amd makes me feel that my participation is provisional and my conversation is in quotation marks." ?

And further more, what does "converstaion in quotation marks" mean? Please forgive me if this question sounds a dumb one but I am not a native Englis speaker.

> I never stopped feeling like an impostor, a New Yorker disguised in a
>   sensible English raincoat. Even the most familiar things — Trafalgar
>   Square; the food hall at Harvey Nichols; the best bookstore in the
>   city, Hatchard’s on Piccadilly — felt at a remove, my participation
>   provisional, my conversation in quotation marks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of artistically creative use of language. The figurative use of "quotation marks" would be the same in any language that uses them for the written form.

Answer (score 2):

"My conversation in quotation marks" refers to the feeling that everything the writer is saying feels forced, or unoriginal, and that the writer doesn't feel like he is really participating; his words feel meaningless and scripted. That is my interpretation. As far as I know, that passage is not grammatically incorrect in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I understand correctly, the last part of the sentence has the world "felt" abbreviated. The original sentence of the last point can be written as "Even the most familiar things felt my conversation in quotation marks." - which, to me, does not make much sense. Does the author mean "Even the most familiar things is felt that my conversation in quotation marks.", if it's the case, why "is felt that" can be replaced with just the verb "felt"?

Comment: "Felt" in the last sentence is not, to my knowledge, abbreviated in any way. The use of the word "felt" is not in the traditional sense, i.e. touching, but rather is used in the sense of metaphysically (emotionally), experiencing the emotions described. You may have thought that "felt" was abbreviated because of the "—" symbols, but that is just a stylistic symbol used to indicate examples related to but separate from the main passage. I hope this is helpful, as I'm unsure quite how to explain this.